# Custom User Profile Picture On My Sites Possible?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property

Besides the default user profile picture we want to create a new property for a second profile  picture which is directed to business contacts etc.

Is it possible to create a second custom profile picture?

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **Add a custom profile property "ProfilePic2"** (not sure if you can have it be of type image, or if it would have to be a link to an image library)

   Central Admin -> Application Management -> Manage Service Applications -> Your Profile Service     Application -> Manage User Properties -> New Property
2. **Create a custom web part that displays the image**

   SPServiceContext serviceContext = SPServiceContext.GetContext(SPContext.Current.Site);
   SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
   UserProfile user = profileManager.GetUserProfile(false);
   var secondProfilePic = user["ProfilePic2"]
3. **Add the webpart to your profile page and use audience targeting** to display it for your business contacts.

Comment: This requires a SharePoint Server Standard license and uses the Microsoft.Office.Server.UserProfiles dll

Answer (score 2):

You could do this by creating a custom or modified OOB web part that you inserted on the page.

You would need to relate a person to this person, for example by adding a Person property to the user profile called BusinessContact and retrieve it using a fixed keyword query in a content query web part.